# UIProgressBar restarts while downloading through NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsurlconnection, uiprogressbar

In my app, I have 2 view. first view is table view which contains list of videos and second view displays sync button to download video from url.

Process:

FirstView (Clicked on Any Row)---> SecondView (Navigation)

SecondView ---> click on sync ---> downloading starts with NSURLConnection and UIProgressBar starts updating.

When I pop SecondView to FirstView, downloading is in progress. Then again If I click on same row of FirstView ---> SecondView, still downloading in progress but UIProgressBar becomes zero.

I need when I push & pop views my progress bar should not be affected while downloading.

Any suggestion/sample code guys. Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you sure you're pushing the same SecondView instance? is it a field of the FirstView or are you creating it on the fly?

Comment: yes, I am pushing same second view instance....

Answer (score 0):

Take progress bar in app delegate